# Dont recieve any messages from methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I don't receive any messages from the controller. The method works, but without showing messages.

```
def create
      @post = Post.new(post_params)
      @post.user_id = current_user.id if user_signed_in?
        if @post.save
          redirect_to current_user, flash: {success: "Post was created"}
        else
          render :new, flash: {alert: "Some errors"}
        end
  end
```

And it doesn't matter will it be a happypass or not.

Comment: Have you iterated flash messages and displayed them in UI i.e in  application.html.erb ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use flash messages in controller when redirecting you need to use:

```
flash.alert = "Some errors"
```

or

```
flash[:alert] = "Some errors"
```

if you want render:

```
flash.now[:notice] = "Some errors"
render :new
```

But remember, use flash.now when rendering and flash when redirecting

Here you can search the details about this subject:
https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/11/rails-flash-messages/

Comment: While this will work the premise is untrue. `redirect_to` can accept flash options https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Redirecting/redirect_to The issue is more likely that "success" is not one of the 2 built in FlashHash keys (:alert, :notice) and there for it must be handled differently on the UI side